# WPF TextBox Style When Disabled

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a simple TextBox style. I want to create a trigger to change the colors when the textbox is disabled:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource NormalFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyName}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource listItemHighlightBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource disabledArrowBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

When I use the trigger, the textbox disappears

What's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any warning messages in the console? do the resources defenetly exist? Are they visible against the background and not transparent(this has happened to me before)?

Comment: No warnings. yes, the resources exist. If I remove the " <Setter Property="Template">" section then the textbox appears.

Answer (score 8):

A ControlTemplate **replaces** the template for that control type. It looks like you're misunderstanding its usage. Before the triggers, try adding some visual objects to display, such as a border, and that will appear. Better yet, don't use a ControlTemplate at all...you only need to set a property trigger on the style, e.g:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```